# Why is min-height not working on background?

Tags: html, css, image, background, height

I've added an background to a div class. What I want is for the image height to always have the same height as the browser window, which I tried to achieve with min-height= 100%. I don't get it to work though.. Any suggestions?

HTML:

```
<div id="top" class="jumbotron">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.jumbotron {
    background: no-repeat center center url('top.jpg');
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

Comment: You can safely drop the prefixes... except of course you want to support the 0.2% of the people who run an outdated browser;) http://caniuse.com/#search=background-size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The body and the html have to fill the 100% height:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%
}
```

Comment: Still doesn't work.. Only the top ~100 px of the image is showing.

Comment: could you post a fiddle ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/jonelm01/znu8k7qn/ 

Appreciate the help! just started coding

Comment: the html needs the same rule of 100% height

Comment: your are welcome! please mark the question as solved ;)

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your jumbotron class:

```
min-height: 100vh;
```

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dgo3sz0a/